Are out struct parameters automatically initialized in C++ when using P/Invoke in C#?
I encountered an issue where allocating memory for a struct with new in the C++ function does not correctly transfer the instance back to C#.
It seems that the correct approach is to avoid using new in the C++ function and directly set the values of the out parameter. However, I couldn't find documentation that explicitly describes this behavior or explains how out parameters automatically handle instance creation.
Do you have this information somewhere on Microsoft Document?
I would like to know if you know of it.
C++ code:
struct MyStruct {
    int value1;
    float value2;
};
    
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetValues(MyStruct* outStruct) {
    // outStruct = new MyStruct();  // NG
    outStruct->value1 = 42;
    outStruct->value2 = 3.14f;
}

C# code:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct {
    public int value1;
    public float value2;
}
    
[DllImport("MyNativeLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void GetValues(out MyStruct result);
    
public static void TestInterop() {
    MyStruct result;
    GetValues(out result);
}


The pointer is passed by value=copy, assigning to outStruct is assigning to the local function parameter not to the argument the caller passed. Inside the function you can change the data the pointer to points to but you cannot point the pointer somewhere else.

"how out parameters automatically handle instance creation" - they don't. The creation of the instance is done in your case on the C# side with: MyStruct result;. A pointer to this instance is then passed to C++, and it gets filled via this pointer by the C++ function.

@shingo the suggested dupe is only addressing half of the issue - here we also have the C# side which is not addressed at all in the dupe. Maybe we should reopen ?

@wohlstad I reopened the question.

@shingo thanks, extended my comment above into a complete answer.

Thank you, everyone! I misunderstood that unless I use new, the instance for MyStruct result; would not be created. I now understand that the instance is created on the stack when the MyStruct result; declaration is executed in C#. Additionally, I realized that the pointer is passed to C++ by value, which means it allows modifying the data it points to, but not the pointer itself.
Thank you again for clarifying these points!

@kinton great, happy to help !


Are out struct parameters automatically initialized in C++ when using P/Invoke in C#?

The answer is: no.
I am not aware of specfific documentation that specifies this, it's simply a basic issue of how C++ works, regardless of P/Invoke.

how out parameters automatically handle instance creation

They don't.
The creation of the instance is done in your case on the C# side with:
MyStruct result;

Note that since MyStruct is a struct and therefore a value-type, it does not require newing (although it's optional).
The instance is created on the stack.
A pointer to this instance (outStruct) is then passed to C++, and it gets filled via this pointer by the C++ function.
A side note:
The reason that using outStruct = new MyStruct(); inside GetValues did not have the effect you expected is that in C++ (as well as C) parameters are generally passed by value (in C++ we also have pass-by-ref but this is not the case here).
In this case the pointer (holding an address) is passed by value. Changing the pointer itself in the function will not affect the caller.
In order to affect the caller you need to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer.
See this post for more info: C++ why double pointer for out/return function parameter?.
